# Why do I get notifications about new Photos memories from a decade ago?

Tags: macos, photos, notifications

Every so often, I get a notification from Photos (on macOS) that I have a new memory. But it's not of recent events. I just got a new memory that includes some pictures I took, and imported into my Mac, nearly 10 years ago.

Why I am I getting these new memories for such old photos all of a sudden? Is Photos just scanning my memories when I have extra processing power and analyzing them?

Comment: I loathe this "feature." I hate that it won't stay off. Tim can use his fam to train his AI's, not mine.

Answer (score 1):

10 year old photos must have been scanned for faces and scenes by now. Whatever new processing happens might be due to some changes or features they bring to Photos or Siri.

As far as memories are concerned from [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207023),

> Rediscover favorite and forgotten moments from deep in your photo library. Memories automatically creates curated collections of your most meaningful photos and videos.

So (These are my guesses) whichever photos involve you in a happy state, your friends, or those shared or opened a lot would appear back.